# For MSVC 2015 with Clang and Codegen, how do I get -ast-dump to work?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I have installed the Clang and Codegen for Visual C++ 2015. I made a new console application which prints out "Hello, world!" and set the Platform Toolset in both Debug x86 and Release x86 to:

> Clang 3.7 with Microsoft CodeGen (v140_clang_3_7)

I turned off precompiled headers and under C/C++ -> Command Line, I added a new command in both Debug x86 and Release x86:

> -ast-dump

I then build the program in Debug mode. The program builds successfully and gives the expected results; however, there is this warning from clang.exe:

> 1>  Source.cpp
>
> 1>clang.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '-ast-dump'
>
> 1>  tester5.vcxproj -> c:\users\erika\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\tester5\Debug\tester5.exe

Why was the argument -ast-dump left unused during the compilation? How do I get Clang, from here, to dump the AST?

Comment: Note that there is binary clang-check that can dump ast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `-Xclang -ast-dump` (along with whatever other options you fancy)

Comment: Thanks! That worked, though the dump is very very long! All the program does is include <iostream> and print "Hello, world!"

Comment: Yes, `<iostream>` is in itself rather large... And since that is part of the source compiled, clang will dump the ast for it... No way around that - other than "replace it with printf and use `extern int printf(const char* fmt, ...);`